# Return from forEachLine

Tags: closures, kotlin

I have this method

```
private fun getDeviceType(): Device {
    ExecuteCommand().forEach {
        if (it == "my search string") {
            return Device.DEVICE_1
        }
    }
    return Device.UNKNOWN
}
```

where `ExecuteCommand()` actually does a `cat file` and returns a list of the file contents. So instead of executing a shell command, I changed it to

```
private fun getDeviceType(): Device {
    File(PATH).forEachLine {
        if (it == "my search string") {
            return Device.DEVICE_1
        }
    }
    return Device.UNKNOWN
}
```

But now compiler complains that `return is not allowed here`.

How can I exit from the closure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The former example works because `forEach` is an [inline method](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns), while `forEachLine` is not. However, you can do this:

```
private fun getDeviceType(): Device {
    var device = Device.UNKNOWN
    File(PATH).forEachLine {
        if (it == "my search string") {
            device = Device.DEVICE_1
            return@forEachLine // Exits the closure only
        }
    }
    return device
}
```

Comment: Yup, the error is because it is because it is not inlined. Also I just saw IntelliJ suggest `return@forEachLine`. I did not know about this syntax! I was hoping to return the device directly from the closure, but this will do. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Sequence<String>` of the lines in the file:

```
private fun getDeviceType(): Device {
    File(PATH).useLines { lines ->
        lines.forEach {
            if (it == "my search string") {
                return Device.DEVICE_1
            }
        }   
    }

    return Device.UNKNOWN
}
```

For smaller files it is also possible to read the lines into a list:

```
private fun getDeviceType(): Device {
    File(PATH).readLines().forEach {
        if (it == "my search string") {
            return Device.DEVICE_1
        }
    }   

    return Device.UNKNOWN
}
```